# Finding the points of a paramertized curve where a tangent line has slope 3?

Tags: parametric

I have a curve at $c(t) = (-5t^2-3t+4,t^3-9t+5)$ and given a slope for the tangent line of $3$.  I would like to find the point $(x,y)$ where this occurs.

What I did is took the derivatives of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, came up with an equation for the slope of a tangent $y'(t)/x'(t)$ and then set that equal to 3.  That gave me $t=-10,0$ which I then plugged back into the original $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ which gave me the points $(4,5)$ and $(-466,905)$.  This doesn't seem to be the answer, however, and I'm stumped as to why.  I did another similar problem and this method gave me the correct answer.  I feel like I might be missing points, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably your $c'(t)=(-10t-3,3t^2-9)$ and you solved $\frac{3t^2-9}{-10t-3}=3$  The $y$ coordinate at $t=-10$ is $(-10)^3-9(-10)+5=-1000+90+5=-905$

Comment: Yeah, I just realized this.  Thank you for the response.  I was tearing my hair out over something so simple.